# NetSuite - get/update custom record type with php toolkit

Tags: php, netsuite

I have a custom Record Type which has a 3 fields. 1 field is a List type and the parent is transaction.

How can I search for these custom record type data from the php toolkit? I need to search the custom data by the PO number.

Thanks in advance